# How do I get Angular to play nicely with Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, routes, angular-routing

I'm using Rails 4.2.3, Devise and AngularJS.  I've set up Devise so that it will accept and render JSON and the rest of my Rails app is pretty much just an API which is also rendering JSON in the response.

My Angular config looks like:

```
angular.module('beer', ['ngRoute']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/beers', {
            templateUrl: "../templates/beers.html",
            controller:  "BeersCtrl"
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl: "../templates/login.html",
            controller:  "LoginCtrl"
        });
    });
```

The problem I'm having is if somebody visits a URL and the session has expired, Devise will redirect to `/users/sign_in` to have them login.  If the original URL that was visited is something like `http://localhost:3000/#/beers` and they're not authenticated, Devise redirects to `http://localhot:3000/users/sign_in/#/beers`

The redirect causes Angular to still see the `/beers` route, and therefore the login page is not rendered.  I'm unsure how to get Rails or Angular to know about each others URL's and handle them appropriately.

For instance, is there a way to have Rails redirect to something like `http://localhost:3000/#/users/sign_in` or maybe there is some way to have Angular see `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in` and know that it should load up the LoginCtrl?  Or, is there something I'm missing that would make this entire thing a lot easier to accomplish?

Comment: You shouldn't be serving the index page from `users/sign_in` ...it should be routing back to the root in all instances that aren't assets or api paths. Your issue is with server config..not angular

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean.  I'm currently just using the rails server, webbrick. The only config that is going on is with `devise_for :users` and `resources :beers` in my routes.rb file...   Devise is what is redirecting to `/users/sign_in` when it hits an action that requires authentication but the user is currently not authenticated.

Comment: this might help you, http://www.ademartutor.com/authentication-with-devise-and-angularjs/

Comment: @charlietfl I figured out what you were saying.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: ignore anything in the url hash at server... angular should manage all the routing using the hash

Answer (score 0):

@charlietfl gave me a bit of a hint in the comments of my question.  What I wound up doing was reorganizing my Rails routes a bit.  I put the devise stuff as well as my BeersController inside of a namespace and any route that isn't accessing something in that namespace gets redirected to the index page with a hash.

For example; If a user visits `/beers` the rails routes will catch that and change it to `/m/#/beers`.  `/m/` maps to `application#index` in my Rails routes.

So, my Rails `routes.rb` file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api do
        devise_for :users, :controllers => {
            sessions: 'sessions',
            registrations: 'registrations'
        }
        resources :beers
    end

    root 'application#index'

    get '/m/' => 'application#index'
    get '*path' => redirect('/m/#/%{path}')
end
```

My Angular routes look the same.

**Side Note**:
For some strange reason, I couldn't get `redirect('/')` to work. It appears as if in Rails 4.2.3, that just using a `/` as an argument to `redirect` does nothing as for some reason it doesn't think it's referencing the absolute URI by doing that.  So, for instance, if a user went to `http://blah.com/cats/meow` the Rails redirect would just redirect to the same URL. I would expect it to redirect to `http://blah.com/`, yet it does not.

**Furthermore**: If you run into trouble with Devise when you're trying to post to it and get JSON back, make sure you're posting to `/api/users/sign_in.json` and your payload looks something like:

```
api_user: {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password'
}
```

That threw me for a bit of a loop, as I didn't expect the payload to need to change with the namespace.